# Picking the most efficient data structure

Tags: python

I don't have a CS background and frequently come into the following problem. I have a text file with the following content:

```
abacial;abadengo;monástico;monacal;clerical;eclesiástico
abacora;avasalla;somete;sojuzga;supedita;rinde;acosa;hostiga
abacorar;acosar;acometer;sujetar
abacá;cabuya;cáñamo;fibra;filamento;pita
```

All words in the same line are synonyms. I want to load this in a data structure such that it is efficient to look up the synonyms of a given word. For example given the query:

```
'abadengo'
```

it should find it in the first line and return the remaining words:

```
['abacial', 'monástico', 'monacal', 'clerical', 'eclesiástico']
```

I don't need working code, I only hints on how this should be done efficiently. The only idea that occurs to me is to create a dict with each word as keys and a list with the synonyms as values, but this seems wasteful memory wise. I have also thought of some sort of graph but have never done this before and don't know wether there is a better solution.

Comment: You can simply use a `dict` with one key for each word in the entire corpus, and the values being all the synonyms for that word.  It will probably be more efficient to store the list of synonyms including the word itself, so that you have the exact same lists used multiple times, because Python uses "reference counting" to avoid duplicating data...if you remove words from their own synonym lists you will need to store separate lists for each key which is counter-productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid wasting memory, use a `dict` recording **the same** tuple (tuples are more memory-efficient than lists) for every synonym (including itself), then to look up use a little function to remove the duplication.  I.e:

```
syndict = {}
with open('the_file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        syns = tuple(line.strip().split(';')(
        for word in syns:
            syndict[word] = syns
def lookup(word):
    syns = syndict.get(word, ())
    return [w for w in syns if w!=word]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think *Roget's Thesaurus*, has two parts. An index that pairs each word with a number (sometimes several numbers) and a set of numbered synonym lists. efficiency is a slippery concept this way is space efficient, but erquires two lookups to find the answer.